# choropleth_geojson TypeError: descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'int'

Tags: python, geojson, choropleth

I´m trying to combine a geojson file with csv data in a choropleth map using choropleth_geojson, as in [minimal_example.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc67F.png) sample:

```
import choropleth_geojson as cg
import pandas as pd
import json
import plotly.offline as offline

mapbox_access_token = 'key'

df = pd.read_csv('indicadores_ma.csv',usecols=['geocod','Impacto (2015)'],sep=';')

with open(r'county_ma.geojson') as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)

northamerica = cg.choropleth(mapbox_access_token, df, geojson, 'geocod')
fig = northamerica.choroplot()

offline.plot(fig, auto_open=True)
```

The input datafiles are:

**indicadores_ma.csv

[image]

**county_ma.geojson**

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [[[[-42.815, -5.3142],...]]]]
            },
            "properties": {
                "geocod": 2112209,
                "name": "Timon/MA"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [[[[-41.8141, -2.7393],...]]]
            },
            "properties": {
                "geocod": 2100907,
                "name": "Araioses/MA"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In

```
fig = northamerica.choroplot()
```

I´m getting the error message:

```
File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2217, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer

TypeError: descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'int'
```

What I am doing wrong?

File used in this message can be download from [here](https://mega.nz/#!55QQkCJK!kYaXpR14A0T5eV4wVj0Q-wqcBMOHpN0ngiZIgrpZ22k).

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Also, do some research on the error message, just use any searchengine. You should be able to find explanations what it means easily, many of them even here.

Comment: I already did both things. The example is described here, and it´s very simple, with only two records in each file. I put a link to the source code and geojson and csv files. And, of course, I googled before ask here.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. In the sample data, there´s no name for the first column of the csv file. It makes pandas assume that the first column should be used as the index column, and it was a string.

In my data, I specified all column names, so pandas creates an integer index column, which generates the error message when choropleth_geojson tries to convert index values to lower case. The solution is to specify the index column in dead_csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv('indicadores.csv',index_col=[0],usecols=['geocod','Impacto (2015)'],sep=';')
```